# Inserting data into tables that reference each other using Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring

I'm importing data to tables that were automatically created using the @Entity annotation. It works fine for the parent table, but when I import data into the child table, somehow the data doesn't reference each other.

The parent table ProductPopularity

```
@Entity

public class ProductPopularity{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private long sales;

private long clicks;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<UserReview> reviews;

@NotNull
private long productID;
```

The child table:

```
@Entity
public class UserReview {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private int quality;

private int connectivity;

@NotNull
long userID;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@NotNull
@JsonBackReference
private ProductPopularity productPopularity;
```

Ihe import.sql file:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_POPULARITY (id, sales, clicks, productID) VALUES (1, 50, 150, 101);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_POPULARITY (id, sales, clicks, productID) VALUES (2, 88, 250, 102);

INSERT INTO USER_REVIEW (id, quality, connectivity, userID, PRODUCT_POPULARITY_ID) VALUES(1, 5, 5, 100, 1);
```

In my restController, I search for the ProductPopularity and the UserReviews via the pathVariable ProductID (review.getProductPopularity.getProductID()).

The rest call .../101/productPopularity returns the expected
{"id":1,"sales":50,"clicks":150,"productID":101}

However, the rest call .../101/userReviews returns am EmptyList []. When inserting a user review manually through Java code, it works...

Comment: Why is the call `.../101/productPopularity` instead of `.../productPopularity/1`?

Comment: Why don't write the back reference into your entity ? Why don't write the the Column reference ?

Comment: Make sure to correct the entity relationships first:

`@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="productPopularity")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<UserReview> reviews;`

And on the owner side of the relationship you need to specify the join column:

`@NotNull
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="PROD_ID")`
private ProductPopularity productPopularity